# Machine cannot connect to SSL website

Tags: ssl, https

I have two machines that I use to submit data to a secure HTTPS website using a C# program. One of them has no trouble, but the other one fails handshake. I've noticed that the working machine sends a Client Hello with a 20 Cipher Suites, while the one that doesn't work only sends 4. Using IISCrypto, I've been able to ensure that both machines have exactly the same ciphers enabled.

Does anyone have any recommendations of how to troubleshoot this issue?

Code used to connect:

```
    try {
        var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} Available", url));
        } else {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} Returned, but with status: {1}", url, response.StatusDescription));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} unavailable: {1}", url, ex.Message));
    }
```

Comment: It connect from what ? Internet Explorer ?

Comment: .Net program that essentially does a post. I get a SSL/TLS channel could not be created and WireShark shows a Handshake Failure: 40.

Comment: What library your .Net program use ? as from there I suspect a coding error. Try with curl in exemple if you can post the data

Comment: For testing purposes, I wrote a test application to eliminate the possibility of a coding error. New app does nothing except reach out and try to touch the website: I'm including my code in the question

Comment: I could help with SSL, but in C. I'am an old school coder. I does not know if the question would be better moved on stackexchange to get more attention.

Comment: I can suggest that to test out if it's the .Net library in error, http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/311/sending-http-post-using-curl-command/. Do a wireshark while it send to see how it react (curl got a windows port btw)

Comment: To move I will flag the question, usually they got moved fast

Answer (score 3):

To troubleshot SSL problems I am using a network sniffer like Wireshark and look for SSL ALERT messages. The message will tell you why remote endpoint closed the connection.

See: SSL [Alert protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Alert_protocol) on Wikipedia page.

Comment: I'm getting a HANDSHAKE FAILURE 40 in WireShark. What would be the next troubleshooting step?

Comment: Check the list of ciphers offered by both endpoints. I think there is no match.

Comment: IISCrypto says all of the ciphers are enabled, but the actual Cipher list in WireShark only has 4 (which are not supported by the server). Could this be some sort of security or permissions issue?

Comment: I think it is a configuration issue. But when you take the capture, is possible, take it on both machines. I've seen cases when there was a firewall on the path that was changing the packets. Another time it was a broken network stack in a VPN software, even if the VPN was not connected.